# How does Xcode know which files to display in the project navigator?

Tags: xcode

I have a file that's in my filesystem and in my pbxproj, but when I try to show it in the navigator, the file can't be found. Also, files using its methods give the "method not found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of file is it?  a .m or .h file?

If you can't find it in the navigator, try using the search field which is at the bottom of the list of files and folders.  It looks like this:

[image: Use The Search Field]

If that doesn't work, open up the Target's Build Phases and look at the list of files to be compiled, like below.

[image: Reveal In Project Navigator]
Holding down the command key while clicking on the file you want will bring up a contextual menu with a "Show In Project Navigator".

If you don't see the file when looking at the list of files to compile, chances are pretty good you simply need to *add* the file to the project.